# Justify elements with fix space (variable width)

Tags: html, css, justify

I have a container with a variable number of elements in it.
The elements should be justified but with a fix space between (e.g. `20px`).
That means the width of every element has to adapt.

For example this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <img src="...">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="...">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="...">
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.container {
    text-align: justify;
}

div.container div {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

div.container div img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

At the end it should look like this (this picture shows two examples: 2 elements and 3 elements; the width is dynamic but the space fix [20px]):

[image: picture showing elements]

It should work with a **different number of child elements**.

Is there a professional way to do this with CSS?

**EDIT**: I should mention that this fix space is a %-value!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If using [Flexbox](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-flexbox/#flex) is an option, you could add `flex: 1` to the flex items and also a margin property with a fixed value as follows:

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsbin.com/kecijo/2/edit)**

```css
div.container { display: flex; }

div.container div {
  height: 50px; /* Just for demo */
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

div.container :first-child { margin-left: 0; }
```

Actually, `flex: 1` is a shorthand of [`flex-grow: 1;`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-flexbox/#propdef-flex-grow) in this case.

Comment: flexbox is not supported in IE8 and IE9, I suppose using the table is a better idea as @Salman did in his answer.

Comment: @4dgaurav That's why I started my answer with `If using Flexbox is an option...` :)

Comment: Thank you for your great answer, it works perfect. Of course the IE8 and IE9 is a problem, but it's awesome. I can't use the table-cell-solution because my fix space is a percentage-value.

Comment: +1 @HashemQolami Yes I saw that..:) your answer is a great solution to the problem if IE9 is not needed.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `display: table` and `display: table-cell` for this:

```css
.container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 10px 0;
  border-collapse: separate;
  background: palevioletred;
}
.container div {
  display: table-cell;
}
.container img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div><img src="//dummyimage.com/200x100/000/CCC"></div>
  <div><img src="//dummyimage.com/300x100/000/CCC"></div>
  <div><img src="//dummyimage.com/400x100/000/CCC"></div>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="container">
  <div><img src="//dummyimage.com/200x100/000/CCC"></div>
  <div><img src="//dummyimage.com/400x100/000/CCC"></div>
</div>
<hr/>
<div class="container">
  <div><img src="//dummyimage.com/600x100/000/CCC"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Edit: I should mention that this fix space is a %-value!

Comment: @LucaNateMahler: you can add a padding on table cells instead of boder spacing. However, the first and last cells will have unnecessary padding on left and right side respectively. See http://jsfiddle.net/salman/937vb7hj/3/

Comment: @LucaNateMahler: there is a solution that uses two additional divs to "clip" the first and last padding. Revising answer.

Comment: @Salman A: Thank your very much. I think I will use the Flex-method. Because I forgot to mention that there are elements which are big like 2 elements.